# List/Detail pattern: Auto-select the first item

Tags: ember.js

i'm trying to implement the very common list/detail pattern, like the tables in the peepcode example or the blog posts in the recent tom dale screencast. Only in my case the first item should be selected and the details shown when you enter the common /items route. So when you go to /items, it should automatically change the url to /items/1 and display the list as well as the details.

This is what i tried:

```
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Item.find();
  },

  redirect: function () {
    if(Ember.isEmpty(this.modelFor('item'))) {
      firstItem = this.model().get('firstObject');
      this.replaceWith('item', firstItem);
    }
  }
});
```

Complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ralph/zeKH9/5/

Problem is, when you add the redirect to the items route, the list of items is not displayed any more, only the item details (try removing the redirect part in the ItemsRoute to see what I mean).

So, what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you redirect, you need to redirect from one route to a different route.

`item` is nested inside `items`. So I guess Ember.js is getting confused, because transitioning to `item` does not mean leaving `items`.

Instead of redirecting from `items` to `item`, you should redirect from `items.index` to `item`.

`item` is included in `items`  which means `items` -> `item` does not make much sense.

`item` is not included in `items.index` which means `items.index` -> `item` is a different route, and so should work.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/zeKH9/7/)

Comment: Exactly! I only need to transition from items.index, this is the part I was missing. Thank you very much, and thank you for updating the fiddle. This made your point very clear. :)